# Uninstall Enlightenment E16 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, uninstall, enlightenment

How can I uninstall e16 from Ubuntu 10.04
I have Gnome and KDE installed too, which i want to keep
Thanks

Comment: if you add the "how" you installed it, you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have used the Ubuntu Software Center, you can go [there](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/e16) and uninstall by clicking at "Remove" button.

Else you can open a terminal and paste: `sudo apt-get purge e16`